# Creating Database in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I am a very beginner in PHP & mysql.
I was searching for the syntax for creating a new database and found the following:
*(( Assuming I am trying to create "employee" database))*

```
$result= mysql_create_db("employee", $DBconnect);

$SQLString = "CREATE DATABASE $employee";
$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLString, $DBconnect);

$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE 'employee';

$createdb=mysql_create_db(employee, $dbconnect);
```

**Can anyone help me to figure the differences between all of those?? PLZ let me know if there is any syntax mistakes!!**

Comment: Syntax mistakes:

    `$SQLString = "CREATE DATABASE \`employee\`";  // was "CREATE DATABASE $employee";`

Comment: You should not be using mysql_* functions as the extension has been deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead!

Answer (score 2):

You generally shouldn’t be creating databases dynamically. What’s this for?

Anyways, this:

```
$result = mysql_create_db("employee", $DBconnect);
```

uses the deprecated `mysql_` extension, and it shouldn’t be used. It also creates a database named “employee”.

This:

```
$SQLString = "CREATE DATABASE $employee";
$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLString, $DBconnect);
```

squashes errors and uses the deprecated `mysql_` extension, and it shouldn’t be used. It creates a database with the name of whatever’s in `$employee`.

This:

```
$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE 'employee';

$createdb=mysql_create_db(employee, $dbconnect);
```

is syntactically invalid, doesn’t use the `$sql` variable, uses a deprecated extension, uses `$dbconnect` instead of `$DBConnect`, and attempts to use the constant `employee` and probably fails over to the literal `'employee'`. Shouldn’t be used.